# Why does the shelve module in python sometimes create files with different extensions?

Tags: python, unix, pickle, shelve

I'm running a Python program which uses the `shelve` module on top of `pickle`. After running this program sometimes I get one output file as `a.data` but at other times I get three output files as `a.data.bak`, `a.data.dir` and `a.data.dat`.

Why is that?

Comment: It's probably the program doing that. The [shelve](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e0c0bcd60033/Lib/shelve.py) module itself doesn't do anything like this.

Comment: `"As a side-effect, an extension may be added to the filename and more than one file may be created."` [(c)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve.open) This doesn't answer _why_, though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is quite some indirection here. Follow me carefully.

The `shelve` module is implemented on top of the [`dbm` module](http://docs.python.org/library/dbm.html). This module acts as a facade for 3<sup>(*</sup> different specific DBM implementations, and it will pick the first module available when creating a new database, in the following order:

1. [`dbm.gnu`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm.gnu), Python module for the GNU DBM library; you would use it directly if you needed the extra functionality it offers over the base `dbm` module (it lets you iterate over the keys in stored order and 'pack' the database to free up space from deleted objects).
2. [`dbm.ndbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm.ndbm), a proxy module using either the `ndbm`, BSD DB and GNU DBM libraries (choosen [when Python is compiled](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/240bcf82a11fe7433a61da70605e924c53b88096/setup.py#L1208-L1498)).
3. [`dbm.dumb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm.dumb), a pure-python implementation.

It is this range of choices that makes `shelve` files appear to grow extra extensions on different platforms.

The `dbm.dumb` module is the one that adds the `.bak`, `.dat` and `.dir` extensions:

> Open a dumbdbm database and return a dumbdbm object. The filename argument is the basename of the database file (without any specific extensions). When a dumbdbm database is created, files with `.dat` and `.dir` extensions are created.

The `.dir` file is moved to `.bak` as new index dicts are committed for changes made to the data structures (when adding a new key, deleting a key, or by calling [`.sync()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#dbm.dumb.dumbdbm.sync) or [`.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#dbm.dumb.dumbdbm.close)).

It means that the *other* three options for `anydbm` are not available on your platform.

The other formats may give you other extensions. The `dbm` module may use `.dir`, `.pag` or `.db`, depending on what library was used for that module.

---

<sup>(*</sup> Python 2 had *four* dbm modules, it would default to the deprecated [`dbhash` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dbhash.html#module-dbhash), which in turn was built on top of the [`bsddb` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html#module-bsddb). These were both removed from Python 3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. just one other thing. Do you know how can I force my program to use dumbdbm not any other modules for databases?

Comment: Create two empty files with the `.dir` and `.dat` extensions if they do not yet exist, after which `anydbm` will assume there is already a `dumbdbm` database there and use the `dumbdbm` module.

Comment: This makes sense.. but at the same time it's kind of horrible and "non-pythonic".. I would prefer to have it stored as plain text in a "objects.jsons" kind of file. Anyone who needs performance won't be using this anyways. But these multiple files take away from the clarity.

Comment: @avloss: Why is it unpythonic? You get a single API that gives you the same kind of storage across a wide range of platforms. The extensions of the resulting files are an implementation detail. `objects.json` is not going to be as easy to use as `shelve` is.

Comment: Of more concern there is the question, how safe is it to delete .bak one manually, or why dumdbdm is not doing that automatically at some point (when writing process closes shelve object, for example) or at some method call. Or at least under what condition can .bak be safely deleted?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev why is that a concern? The file is a copy of the last state of the `.dir` file and can be deleted whenever you feel the storage is still in a 'sane' state. That's not for `dbm.dumb` to decide, as it can't foresee crashes or bugs. Instead, it replaces the `.bak` file each time a new `.dir` file is written.

Comment: @martijn-pieters Thanks, yes I thought so as well. I have 2 processes, one writer, and one reader. According to docs, multiple writers are not supported, but concurrent readers should be ok. But it seems that sometimes just opening the same shelve object for reading leads to losing data, I though it could be due to some problems with such files (not being synched properly, or being overwritten). Not sure yet, need to watch more.

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev: note that when you _replace_ the value for a key, the `.dir` file is not synched. Call `.sync()` explicitly in such cases.

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev: however, for multiple readers, I'd use a sqlite database instead.

Comment: Yes I'm also thinking to replace shelve temp solution with smth like redis in production.